# Banned from reviewing

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

I recently have been blocked from reviewing for 2 days for failing audits. Today I got unblocked, passed 1 audit and then failed 1.

Now I have a 4 day review ban. I personally think this is unfair as I already passed 1 audit.

Comment: OK... Do you have an actual question here? Aren't you interested in understanding why you failed the audits, for example?

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming I already understand, and i want an unban as this is unjust

Comment: Oh, that. I'm afraid that we're much more likely to disagree with you here. You are not supposed to fail audits at all, so the cooldown is a hint to be more careful next time.

Comment: Looking at the audit failure that triggered this 4 day ban... What made you think that "Requires Editing" was a suitable option there?

Comment: Well a quick review of your review. show that require Editing is use as default flag. Require Editing is when any one can edit the post to make it valuable. not when it need information from OP.

Comment: So you've been banned from editing and banned from reviewing and somehow it is not unfair to other people's posts and flags that you don't know how to do it right.  The machine has a way to stop you, it is a feature.  A bit sad that it had to be added, but some users just don't understand that their contribution can be harmful.

Comment: There are several normal reviews where you also made a suboptimal decision. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21494949): You should have at least edited i -> I. [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21494814): No action needed although "Thank you" should be removed and code has too much indentation. [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21494879): I don't see anything that can be edited by anyone else than op here. [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21494913): No action needed although title contains ??. Other words wrong capitalized.

Comment: A single careless review result may need another 4-5 extra users' work to undo, and that is, if it's still undo-able. I find it extremely unfair to not put some timeout period for careless reviewers.

Comment: Let's take one step back here. *Why* do you want to review? What's your motivation? Why is it that you're frustrated that you can't review for a few days? If the answer is "I want to get the related badges", then I think that's worth reflecting on.

Comment: @DanBron I never knew there were reviewing badges. I just want to review to help out and if I am banned I can’t help put.

Comment: If you keep getting caught by review audits, it means you are not helping as much as you think. Please, re-read the rules and guidance and use this timeout to re-think your approach.

Comment: @yivi I don’t think so

Comment: Think about it; you've been review banned.  That means that you're not helping; you're actually creating more work for other people.  Your motivation may be to help, but just like any other area, overenthusiasm can make it harder for others, as they now have to clean up after you.  The system is designed to ensure that minimal clean up after reviewers is required.  So if you don't want to be banned, don't make decisions that cause additional work for others.

Comment: @DManokhin _" I don’t think so"_ What do you mean? You wont re-read rules and guidance? You are not helping as much as you think?

Comment: yivi, I think he disagrees with your premise he isn't helping. Basically... If the audits keep on catching you, @dmanokhin, that means you likely do non-audited reviews that aren't in line with the expectation of this community. And correcting incorrect reviews is a drain of ressources we shouldn't have to deal with. You are indeed causing a bit more hurt than you seem to realize....

Answer (score 25):

Why do you believe it is unjust? Saying that you shouldn't be banned because you passed one audit is like saying that getting a ticket for jumping a red light is unfair because you did respect a red light at a previous intersection.

Usually, in these cases, the more useful course of action is to use the review ban days to rest and do something else (weekend is coming up, which is always nice), or even try to research the review rules to understand why you keep failing audits.

Hopefully you'll try to be more careful in the future, because next review ban could be double the length of this one if it happens soon enough.

Remember that the review ban is not so much a "punishment", but a cool down period to help you think better about your actions.

Review bans can't really be considered punishment, since review queues are **work**. Punishment that stops you from working for free is **very** light punishment indeed.

Comment: A good place to start is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674). These guidelines should help you make the correct decision next time

Comment: @JessedeBruijne I have already read those guidelines

Comment: @DManokhin considering some of the reviews that have been called out here, I have to ask: did you just now read them, or did you read them before these questionable reviews? Cause if you read them before you started reviewing... might be worth making another readthrough